# Draw something won't let me take my turn

Tags: draw-something

I've got notifications that people have drawn for me, but the game won't let me respond with my own drawing (wont let me take my turn). I've deleted and reinstalled the app but still nothing (iPhone 5). Oddly, when I reinstalled, all my data was still in place (like I never left).

Comment: When you reinstalled, were you logged out? Can you log out at all? Don't have the game installed, just wondering if that will help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone? Stuff can get caught up in your active memory. Whether or not it is installed.